# custom `require` method in CommonJS (specifically Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Is it possible to define a custom `require` method in one module that can be called in another module?

For example, in x/x.js

```
exports.xrequire = function(path) {
   console.log("requiring " + path);
   require(path);
};
```

In y/hello.js

```
console.log("Hello, world!");
```

And then in y/y.js

```
var xrequire = require("../x/x.js").xrequire;
xrequire("hello.js");
```

When y.js is run, "Hello World" should be printed.

I know this seems like a bad idea, but I do have a legitimate reason to do it. ;)

---

The issue with this code is that it tries to load x/hello.js, not y/hello.js — I'd like it to work the same as the standard require.

Comment: Does this not work when you try it?

Comment: The issue is that it tries to load `x/hello.js`, not `y/hello.js` — I'd like it to work the same as the standard require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly could do this.  It would successfully avoid modifying the global `require.paths` array which can [pose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131408/nodejs-what-to-use-instead-of-require-paths) at run time, and shouldn't have an issues with future releases.

You should be able to simply set up a model that you simple `require` into your current app.  According to your example **x.js** should contain.

```
var relative = 'y/';
exports.xrequire = function(path) {
   console.log("requiring " + relative + path);
   return require(relative+path);
};
```

Then you can successfully use your custom `require`.

```
var xrequire = require('x.js'),
    hello = xrequire('hello.js');
```

I don't advise this, but if you wanted to be really **sneaky**, you could override the `require` function.

```
var require = xrequire;
```

I would definitely throughly document this inside your module if you plan to `require` :D this functionality, but it certainly does work.

**EDIT:**

Well you could test for the file and fallback to `require` if it doesn't exist.

```
var relative = 'y/';
exports.xrequire = function(path) {
   var ret;
   try{
     ret = require(relative+path);
     console.log("requiring " + relative + path);
   }catch(e){
     console.log("requiring " + path);
     ret = require(path);
   }
   return ret;
};
```

---

I think you could try adding `process.cwd` to the beginning of the require path to force looking in the correct directory first. In all honesty this would confuse most developers. I would advise just defining a namespace for your app and creating a special require function that retrieves only that namespaced apps special functions.

Comment: I'd like it to be able to work with standard relative paths, just like the default `require` does, not hard coded ones. Thanks though :)

Comment: Why?  Are you wanting `require`s to bubble up or something?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use `xrequire` just like the standard Node `require`, but with additional functionality (e.g., logging—although that is not really what I'm doing). `xrequire` should be able to be included and used in any CJS package.

Comment: `require` has been added as a fallback.  Alternatively you could use `path.exists` to check for the file instead of using a `try{}cach(e){}` block

Comment: This does not work. If I have a new project `z`, then I cannot use `xrequire()` to open files in `z`.

Comment: You never mentioned `z` %)  And wouldn't you use `zrequire()` for the `z` project?  I mean you used `xrequire` for project `x`.  I kinda feel this whole overriding concept is going to add more frustration then help.

Comment: @Lime let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1331/discussion-between-luxun-and-lime)

Comment: That's weird, I never got a notification you opened a chat.  I came back to look at your post's status and found you had opened a discussion.... I added some more comments in the discussion

Answer (score 0):

The CommonJs modules spec requires that `require` be named `require`, and be called with a string literal, to allow build tools to preload modules.

A specific implementation may allow you to do what you want, but it may fail on another implementation, or when you upgrade.

Edit: The above comes from my recollection when I was learning about commonJS modules -- It does not appear to be defined that way in the spec.